# Milnor’s smoothed corners technique for a product of manifolds with boundary and boundary defining functions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, geometric-analysis

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold that we view as the interior of a *compact manifold with boundary* $\overline{M}$. Let $\rho$ be a *boundary defining function* for $\overline{M}$, i.e. $\rho$ is smooth, $\rho > 0$ on $M$, $\partial \overline{M} = \{ \rho=0 \}$ and $d\rho$ does not vanish on $\partial \overline{M}$. By the collar neighborhood theorem, there exists a neighborhood $W$ of the boundary  $\partial \overline{M}$ in $\overline{M}$, $\epsilon > 0$ and a diffeomorphism $\phi : [0,\epsilon) \times \partial \overline{M} \rightarrow W$ such that $\rho \circ\phi$ agrees with the projection to the first component of $[0,\epsilon) \times \partial \overline{M}$. Thus, when we consider points close to the boundary we will use local coordinates of the form $(\rho, y_1, \dots, y_{n-1})$ where $y =  (y_1, \dots, y_{n-1})$ are local coordinates on $\partial \overline{M}$ (we drop $\phi$ in the notation).

The standard example is for $M = \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\overline{M} = \overline{\mathbb{R}^n}$ is the *radial compactification* of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here $M = \mathbb{R}^n$ is compactified into the n-dimensional unit ball where $\partial \overline{M} = \partial \overline{\mathbb{R}^n} = \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is the “sphere at infinity”: for any non zero $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, we consider the coordinates $(\rho,y)$ where $\rho = r^{-1}$ and with $(r,y)$ the polar coordinates of $x$.

The problem I am interested in is **to find a well-defined boundary defining function for the product manifold $\overline{M} \times \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ (which is a manifold with corners) after applying Milnor’s rounding corner process**, which makes it a smooth manifold with boundary. I am going to describe it next ([https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/homsph.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/homsph.pdf), pages 34-37).

Let $X, Y$ be two smooth manifolds with boundary. Using product charts in $X$ with charts in $Y$, $X \times Y \setminus (\partial X \times \partial Y)$ has a given differential structure. Now, applying the collar theorem to both of these manifolds we get that an open set $W_1 \times W_2$ is diffeomorphic (say be $\psi$) to $(\partial X \times \mathbb{R}_+) \times (\partial Y \times \mathbb{R}_+) $, that we identify with  $\partial X \times \partial Y \times (\mathbb{R}_+)^2 $. Now we define $f : \partial X \times \partial Y \times (\mathbb{R}_+)^2 \rightarrow \partial X \times \partial Y \times \mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}$ by $$ f(y_1,y_2,\rho_1, \rho_2) = f(y_1,y_2,2\rho_1 \rho_2, \rho_1^2-\rho_2^2), $$
letting us to pass from corner charts to boundary charts (Milnor does it in polar coordinates in the notes).
This gives a differential structure on $W_1 \times W_2 $ (by $f\circ\psi$), which has smooth overlap with the charts on $X \times Y \setminus (\partial X \times \partial Y)$, giving $X\times Y$ a structure of smooth manifold with boundary. For $X= \overline{M}$ and $Y= \overline{\mathbb{R}}$, we denote by $\overline{N}$ this new smooth manifold with boundary.

So now, I would like to **define a boundary defining function for $\overline{N}$**. The first idea is to mimick what we would do for $M = \mathbb{R}^n$, that is : if $(r_1,y)$ is the polar form of a non zero $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then our radius in $M \times \mathbb{R}$ is $r := \sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2}$ (where $r_2 = \vert z \vert$ for $z \in \mathbb{R}$). Then we choose $\rho := r^{-1} = \frac{\rho_1 \rho_1}{\sqrt{\rho_1^2 + \rho_2^2  }}$, where $\rho_1, \rho_2$ are boundary defining functions for $\overline{\mathbb{R}^n}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ respectively (inverses of $r_1$ and $r_2$). Then for $M$ (abstract), we would define a boundary defining function for $\overline{N}$ given by  $\rho^{-2} := \rho_1^{-2} + \rho_2^{-2}$ (giving $\rho =   \frac{\rho_1 \rho_1}{\sqrt{\rho_1^2 + \rho_2^2  }}$), after having lifted up $\rho_1$, a boundary defining function for $\overline{M}$, to $\overline{M} \times \overline{\mathbb{R}}$  (same for $\rho_2$).

My question is, **how to make sense of smoothness of $\rho$** on the part of the boundary $\{ \rho_1=0, \rho_2=0$ } of $\overline{N}$? Because, a priori, $\rho =   \frac{\rho_1 \rho_1}{\sqrt{\rho_1^2 + \rho_2^2  }}$ is not smooth in $(0,0)$ but I am confused since I feel that it is a matter of notations and definitions. One issue is about the local coordinate $\rho$ and the boundary defining function also denoted by $\rho$, which can lead to mistakes since for a point in the corner of $\overline{M} \times \overline{\mathbb{R}}$, we changed the chart by Milnor’s technique ; thus smoothness of functions such as $\rho$ should be read through these new charts around these points (remember that we dropped $\phi$ in our notation for local coordinates). Another potential problem is that Milnor’s technique uses a homeomorphism which is a diffemorphism away from $(0,0)$, so it is not very clear for me how everything is smooth at the end.

Is it possible to make that more clear? Any help will be very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why not just take $\rho:=\rho_1\rho_2$? It is clearly smooth in $X\times Y\setminus(\partial X\times\partial Y)$, and also in $W_1\times W_2$ since it's just one of the coordinates of $f\circ\psi$ (you are allowed to use the boundary-defining $\rho_1,\rho_2$ to define $\psi$). The condition that the differential be non-zero over $\partial X\times\partial Y$ is again given by the fact that it is a coordinate of $f\circ\psi$.

Comment: Since $(a^2+b^2)^2=(a^2-b^2)^2+4a^2b^2$, the function you are considering is $g:=f_3/(f_4^2-f_3^2)^{1/4}$, where I have decomposed your $f\circ\psi$ as $(f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4)$. But at a point of $\partial X\times\partial Y$, $f_3=f_4=0$ and the differential of $(f_3,f_4)$ has full rank, so your function cannot be smooth.

Comment: @PierrePC Thanks for your answer! Yes I think you’re right, actually my main problem is when i compute the coefficients of a metric on $\overline{N}$ in which i find this $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho_1^2 + \rho_2^2  }}$ (that makes it not smooth). And yes that is probably it, but you mean $f_3 = 2\rho_1\rho_2$ and $f_4 = \rho_1^2 - \rho_2^2$ right? Don’t we have then $\rho = \frac{f_3}{(f_3^2 + f_4^2 )^{\frac{1}{4}}}$? Anyway at the end it’s not smooth :)

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, a $+$ in the denominator. I don't know what you are trying to compute that gives you this function. $\mathbb R^n$ does not have a boundary, so if you want to emulate the Euclidean case the model should be $\mathbb R_+^2$ (the simplest product of manifolds with boundaries). In this case, Milnor says that we can think of it as $\{z\in C:\operatorname{re}z\geq0,\operatorname{re}z\geq0\}$, and that the map $z\mapsto z^2$ "smoothes" this corner to the upper half plane. The smoothed imaginary part is a defining boundary function, i.e. $(a+ib)\mapsto2ab$.